# Zeppelin Air speakers causing interference on wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, speakers, interference

My dad recently bought the new [Bowers & Wilkins Zeppelin Air](http://www.bowers-wilkins.com/iPod_and_Computer_Speakers/iPod_and_Computer_Speakers/Zeppelin_Air/overview.html) speaker system. They allow you to stream music from a computer and other devices to the Zepellin without the need for wires.

Unfortunately, when the Zeppelin is turned on, it is interfering with our entire wireless network. The Zeppelin is correctly configured to stream wirelessly and works flawlessly, but the Internet connection on every computer/laptop drops to unworkable speeds when the Zeppelin is turned on. There are different modes to switch between on the Zeppelin, but when it is turned on, even on the non-wireless mode, the Internet connection is still affected to the same extent as in the wireless mode.

I have tried changing the channel on which the router broadcasts, but it is the same on every channel. It seems to me like it could be a router compatibility issue. The router is a Netgear Wireless-G 108mbps from Sky, and without the Zeppelin works perfectly throughout our house. Any ideas/suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Hi Nick! In the future, please don't cross-post across multiple Stack sites – your question can be migrated automatically if it's off-topic somewhere.

Comment: Sorry I thought the 2 sections were different websites at first (they were separate links from another website) and I only realised after posting.

Comment: Are you saying that even when it's in Ethernet-only mode (no Wi-Fi), and just turned on, but with no one streaming to it, the network performance for the other devices on your network still drops to unworkable speeds? Does disabling the nonstandard/proprietary 108 mbps stuff on the Netgear (switch it to standard B/G mode) make a difference? What security mode are you using on the Netgear?